# Add a new tab to the Service app containing a LWC component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, lightning, salesforce-classic

I created a custom Lightning component and I now want to add it to a new tab in the classic app *Service*. I followed what I could find online about doing that, mainly creating a VisualForce page and adding it to my package. However, my page doesn't appear listed in the choices for new tabs in the Service app setup page. What did I do wrong?

Here's my page

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning" />
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:comunikAppletLWC", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:comunikAppletLWC", {}, "lightning", function(cmp) {});
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Here it's meta file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
    <label>Comunik Applet</label>
    <availableInTouch>true</availableInTouch>
    <confirmationTokenRequired>false</confirmationTokenRequired>
</ApexPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Visualforce page isn't added directly to the App, instead you need to make sure that you create a Visualforce Tab which can then be added to the Service or any other apps.

You can create these from Setup > Tabs > Visualforce tabs.

The full steps to create this can be found in the docs here: [Create Visualforce Tabs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pages_tabs_create.htm&type=5)

Comment: This managed to solve the first issue I was having, but now that I can see the component, it just shows an error. `An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 237577151-277144 (1056366667)`

Comment: It's probably best to raise that as another question then given it's going to be a fairly different answer compared to your initial question and you're going to get more support that way. Although if this answer did solve your initial question it would also be useful to mark it as accepted.