# An internal server error has occurred (1056366667)

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, lightning, salesforce-classic, component

I have put a Lightning component inside a VisualForce page and put that page in a tab in a classic app. ([Add a new tab to the Service app containing a LWC component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/415665/add-a-new-tab-to-the-service-app-containing-a-lwc-component)) This is working fine and I can't see html appearing on the page when I deploy it.

The problem comes when trying to display my component, it instead shows this error:

```
An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1530819035-8072 (1056366667)
```

Where could that be coming from?

Here's my page

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning" />
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:comunikAppletLWC", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:comunikAppletLWC", {}, "lightning", function(cmp) {});
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: so if I understand correctly @identigral, I won't be able to resolve this without talking to their support team?

Comment: Pretty much, yep. The two error Ids that you get are something that only has meaning for the official customer support team (and >= 99% of us here are customers like yourself). There is one Salesforce employee that has answered several GACK questions here, and other than that your only other hope is that someone else has run into the same issue (the part of the error id in the parenthesis).

Comment: Based on error Id (1056366667) some component is missing from vf page. If you want to include the aura component in vf page create an aura app and <aura:dependency> to indicate that it uses the lightning comp.